# Prove that $y(t)= -1$ is the only solution of the initial-value problem $y'=t(l+y)$, $y(0)=-l$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $y(t)= -1$ is the only solution of the initial-value problem
$y'=t(l+y)$, $y(0)=-l$.

So I am not sure actually how to get started on this, I guess the first thing I would do is to integrate both sides to get a function of y:

$$y'=t(l+y)$$

$$y=∫t(l+y)dt$$

I think it would be dt right? Because y is a function of t?

Then I am kind of stuck...

Comment: Really time that you learn C___-L___ theorem...

Comment: I don't know that this theorem is you're talking about. Maybe if you could give me the theorem, or at least what it's called I could look it up.

Comment: Cauchy-Lipschitz. *THE* basic result of the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not $y(t) = -1$ that is a solution, but $y(t) = -\color{red}{l}$ that is the only solution. By separation of variables

$$\int \frac{dy}{l + y} = \int t\, dt$$

which gives

$$\ln|l + y| = \frac{t^2}{2} + C$$

or

$$l + y = Ae^{t^2/2}$$

(Note: $C$ and $A$ are arbitrary constants.) Since $y(0) = -l$, we have $0 = A$. So $l + y(t) = 0$, or $y(t) = -l$. Check $y' = 0$ and $t(l + y) = t(l - l) = 0$. So $y(t) = -l$ is the only solution.

Comment: you don't need to separate the variables to see that $y = -l$ is a solution. what you really need is the uniquness of solutions.

Comment: @abel yes, but I decided to avoid using the existence and uniqueness theorems. My first thought was what you wrote, though.

Comment: how can you avoid? what you have found is a solution. what if there are others? you don't need to perpetuate the idea provident only a palatable answer while you know the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is an ODE with separable variables.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=t(l+y) \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{l+y} = t dt \Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{dx}{l+x} = \int_{0}^tsds \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow\left(\log|l+x|\right)_{x=y(0)}^{x=y(t)} = \left(\frac{s^2}{2}\right)_{s=0}^{s=t} \Rightarrow \log|l+y(t)|-\log|l+y(0)| = \frac{t^2}{2} \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow\log|l+y(t)| = \log|l+y(0)|+\frac{t^2}{2} \Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow|l+y(t)| = |l+y(0)|e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Now, being $y(0) = -l$, then:

$$|l+y(t)|=0 \Rightarrow l+y(t) = 0$$

which mean that $y(t) = -l$ is the unique solution of your ODE.

Answer (score 1):

the uniqueness theorem for first order differential equation says that $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y)$ has a unique solution if $f(t,y)$ and 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous in the domain of your solution. the right handside of your differential equation, $t(l + y),$ satisfies both requirements. and you can see that $y = -l$ is a solution. therefore, is the only solution.